# python encoding error when searching a string

Tags: python, string, unicode, encode

I get the following error while trying to search the string below

ERROR:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd8' in file Hadith_scraper.py on line 44, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

STRING:

```
دَّثَنَا عَبْدَانُ، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنَا عَبْ
```

CODE:

```
arabic_hadith = "دَّثَنَا عَبْدَانُ، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنَا عَبْ"
arabic_hadith.encode('utf8')
print arabic_hadith
if "الجمعة" in arabic_hadith:‎
    day = "5"
else:
    day = ""
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a *byte string*, not a `unicode` value. Trying to encode a byte string in Python 2 means that Python will first try to decode it to `unicode` so that it can then encode.

Use `unicode` values here instead, and make sure you set the codec at the top of the file first. See [PEP 263 - Defining Python Source Code Encodings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) (which your error message pointed you to).

Note that there is **no need** to encode to UTF8 here, that'll only complicate text comparisons:

```
# encoding: utf8
arabic_hadith = u"دَّثَنَا عَبْدَانُ، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنَا عَبْ"
print arabic_hadith
if u"الجمعة" in arabic_hadith:‎
    day = "5"
else:
    day = ""
```

Rule of thumb: decode bytes from incoming sources (files, network data) to Unicode, process only Unicode in your program, and only encode again for any outgoing data.

I urge you to read:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

before you continue.

Comment: I always have problems with Unicode... :( I tried this and it failed with the same error :(

Comment: what if arabic_hadith is a variable? doing this is doesn't solve it: arabic_hadith = u(arabic_hadith)

Comment: @Ossama: Nope, it would not. `arabic_hadith.decode('utf8')` would though.

Comment: Still a problem: arabic_hadith = arabic_hadith.decode('utf8')
  print arabic_hadith
  if u"الجمعة" in arabic_hadith:‎
   day = "5"
  else:
   day = ""

Comment: Non-ASCII character '\xd8' in file Hadith_scraper.py on line 46, but no encoding declared;

Comment: @Ossama: **Did you declare your source encoding**? The error message is quite clear. The `u"الجمعة"` value is still a unicode literal.

Comment: Being the noob I am I dont know how

Comment: @Ossama if you want to use unicode literals in your `*.py` files, you need to start them with a `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` header.

Comment: @Ossama: You need to add a line, at the top (first or second line of the file) starting with `#`, containing the word `coding` followed by `:` or `=` plus the codec used to save the file.

Comment: @Ossama: you could **start** by reading the link the error message provided. It is hotlinked in my answer.